# Unable to convert string to float in Logistic Regression

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I have written the following code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

Spam_model = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', penalty='l1')
print(X_train)

Spam_model.fit(X_train, Y_train)
pred = Spam_model.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(Y_test,pred)
```

It's throwing the following error. What could be the reason for that?

[image]

Comment: Please post any errors or exceptions in text formatting. [Here's why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: If you are working with texts, check tf-idf method. I guess the problem is what Unnamed mentioned below.

Answer (score 0):

Logistic regression works with numbers, not strings. You input a value (or more) and it predicts another. A float is a number with decimals. For example, a 2 is an integer and a 2.53 is a float. What you can do is

```
a = '0.67687980'
print(float(a))
```

Which returns

```
0.67687980
```

However, you cannot do it with a string

```
a = 'Some string'
print(float(a))
```

As it returns:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Some string'
```

If you're using data that isn't numeric, you should convert it all to numbers first to avoid this error

Answer (score 0):

If you have text as data, you need to do [feature extraction](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html) before applying the classifier. Using an [old example](https://scikit-learn.org/0.19/datasets/twenty_newsgroups.html) from sklearn:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
cats = ['alt.atheism', 'sci.space']

newsgroups_train = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='train', categories=cats)
X_train = newsgroups_train.data
Y_train = newsgroups_train.target

newsgroups_test = fetch_20newsgroups(subset='test', categories=cats)
X_test = newsgroups_test.data
Y_test = newsgroups_test.target
```

Data looks like this:

```
Y_train
array([0, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1])

X_train[0][:50]
'From: bil@okcforum.osrhe.edu (Bill Conner)\nSubject'
```

Apply a vectorizer to convert your text into basically numerical features, and then you train the model:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X_train_vec = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_vec = vectorizer.transform(X_test)

model = LogisticRegression(solver='liblinear', penalty='l1')

model.fit(X_train_vec, Y_train)
pred = model.predict(X_test_vec)
accuracy_score(Y_test,pred)

0.906030855539972
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Apart from the TfidfVectorizer. Is there any other strategy one can use?

Comment: you can see text feature attraction under https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html